# Coldfusion RegEx to check strength of password

Tags: regex, coldfusion, passwords, coldfusion-7

I'm using this to (try) to validate a 'strong' password in ColdFusion 7.

```
if ( REFind("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@##$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6}$", myPassword, 1) EQ 0 )
```

However, it is failing. Can someone point out my error?

The criteria I *think* I'm testing is:

- 1 upper
- 1 lower
- 1 number
- 1 special char
- 6 digit min

Footnotes for non-CF people:

- the double hash is to escape the CF hash;
- ColdFusion uses Jakarta ORO 2.0.6 as its regex engine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, well the set of criteria you're trying to test on are bad.

For example, `Pa$5word` meets the criteria but is a bad choice, whilst `my name |z NOT Fr£d` is much stronger but fails (no numbers; different symbols).

Ideally you should look for and existing password strength checker (although I've no idea if there are any existing/good ones out there).

Anyhow, for a simple solution to what you've asked, that spells out exactly what is being checked, just do:

```
<cfif NOT 
    ( len(myPassword) GTE 6
    AND refind('[A-Z]',myPassword)
    AND refind('[a-z]',myPassword)
    AND refind('[0-9]',myPassword)
    AND refind('[!@##$&*]',myPassword)
     )>
```

There is no need/benefit to smushing it all into a single regex.

Comment: however, I'm going to pick on you a bit...
You mention Pa$5word as a 'bad' selection even though it meets the criteria - and you posit that the criteria is poor to begin with. Pa$5word is SIGNIFICANTLY more secure than 'password' as a string...

Comment: And a house of sticks is significantly more secure than a house of straw - but neither stops a big-lunged wolf...

Comment: Remember why you're doing this - you want "secure enough" or "not secure enough". You need to correctly identify which side of the line a value lands; relative magnitude isn't significant.

Comment: not sure how far back CF shortcut codes go, but from CF9 onward you may use "\d" to check for numeric and  and "\W" for non-alphaNumeric:

for digits: `refind('[\d]', myPassword)`

for non-alphaNumeric: `refind('[\W]', myPassword)`

Comment: Another reason to keep checks separate is that you probably want to provide the user with what criteria s/he failed in your system reply, i.e., you probably want to break the checks to separate conditions rather than a single `<cfif ... and ... and ... and ...>`

Comment: The syntax in the answer was chosen for consistency. They're not CF shortcut codes, they're regex shorthand character classes, and work in almost all regex engines (certainly will work as far back as CFMX, probably worked in whatever version refind arrived in). They also don't need to be wrapped inside character class blocks (unless being unioned with other classes). Note also that `\W` is equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` and thus is a significantly different check to `[!@#&$*]` (not necessarily in a bad way; but certainly something that should be understood).

Answer (score 0):

One reason why it might be failing is your business rule is "at least six characters", but your regex enforces exactly six characters.

Also: it'd be helpful it you stated which conditions it fails on. My superficial testing suggests you're fine except for the caveat I mention above.  If you could finetune your question to point out what non-superficial testing that I'm not thinking about is failing, that'd be helpful.

In the real world, I'd also expect what punctuation characters you consider valid, too.  Your list is a bit short.  But that's nowt to do with you current problem.

Comment: Adam - thank you for identifying a problem, but then you didn't offer a correction - making your post more frustrating than helpful - as for stating which 'item' failed - clearly I don't know which one failed... otherwise I would have included that information.

Comment: Sorry I presumed that given you clearly could write a reasonably complex regex, I figured a "second set of eyes" assessment was adequate here, given what the problem seemed to be.  I did not want to insult your intelligence by spoon-feeding you.  As for what was failing and what wasn't, what I meant was like "aA1$aa works, but aA1$aaa does not" (etc).  Which I imagine was within the sort of troubleshooting analysis you had done before posting?  That's all I meant: that sort of info is helpful.

Comment: roger that adam, and I probably KNEW what you meant - i was just in a foul mood - soory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@##\$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}$

Add comma after six since you want to allow more than 6 characters and $ must be escaped with \$

**Update**

Try below, ^ and $ removed from above one

(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@##$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}

Comment: Why does the $ need to be escaped in that context?

Comment: Pritesh - this did NOT work... although i wish it had - it is concise.

Comment: $ doesn't need escape my mistake thanks Adam for pointing it out.
jpmyob try below removed ^ and $.
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@##$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}

Answer (score 0):

fwiw to separate out the different character failures:

```
<cfscript> raRe=[["[a-z]","lowercase"],["[A-Z]","uppercase"],["[\W]","non-alphanumeric"],["[\d]","numeric"]];</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
 <cfloop from=1 to=4 index="idxRe">
  #idxRe#: refind(raRe[idxRe][1], myPassword):<b>#refind(raRe[idxRe][1], myPassword)#</b> myPassword:<b>#myPassword#</b>; re:<b>#raRe[idxRe][1]#</b>; <br />
  <cfif refind(raRe[idxRe][1], myPassword) eq 0><b>Your password must include at least one #raRe[idxRe][2]# character</b><br /></cfif>
 </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

And of course if >=6 is also required:

```
<cfif Len(myPassword) lte 6><b>Your password must be at least 6 characters long</b></cfif>
```

Comment: As commented above, `[\d]` and `[\W]` are unnecessarily long-winded ways of writing `\d` and `\W`. Also, I don't think literal array notation worked in CF7 - it was added in CF8 wasn't it?

Comment: ooooo. busted. Thank you @Peter. CF7 was pretty dumb. elegant answer you posted, too.